# How to select empty fields where null is set to "no" and default is set to "none"

Tags: mysql, sql

So there is some `target_field` which has no default and can't be null how do you select all rows where this field is empty i.e. unpopulated?

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE target_field ???
```

in my case the field is of type varchar(100)

Comment: How do you define "empty i.e. unpopulated". Do you mean a string of length 0?

Comment: perhaps that's my problem...i want to know how to define "empty i.e. populated"...all i know is that the field was never populated. So this could happen if new columns were added to an existing table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this?

```
select * from some_table where target_field = ''
```